# Why Does This For Loop Not Execute?

Tags: vba, excel

This non-looping code executes with no problem:

```
If InStr(1, Sheets(1).Range("A1"), "blah") > 0 Then
    Sheets(2).Range("A1") = Sheets(1).Range("B1")
End If
```

But I need to iterate through several rows; hence, a loop:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    If InStr(1, Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1), "blah") > 0 Then
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
    Else Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = ""
    End If
Next
```

The loop compiles and does not crash, but fails to return any output. Why?

Comment: Sorry to hear that! (Thanks)

Comment: InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1), "blah") returns an integer of -1, 0 or the position in the string it is found.  I would suggest adding in a > < or equal to -1 or 0

Comment: Fair enough. No effect on outcome.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific in what you're expecting. This code works for me. Are you certain there is actually a value in `Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)`?  Have you put a breakpoint on the line:  `Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)` in order to test whether your condition is ever met?

Comment: Yes, there is a value in Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2). Note that the first code block I posted (without the for loop) works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add a 1 and a 0 to your instr formula

```
Instr(1, Sheets(1).Cells(i,1), "blah") > 0
```

Also, are you sure that `Sheets(2)`'s values are the ones to be changed?

Comment: nice catch, I missed that

Answer (score 2):

This should work.  Also noticed that you are referencing the cell and not the value held in the cell

***Note this is a crap way to debug but...what does the msgbox prompt say? It should say 0 or 1 and the second msgbox should tell you what is going to be put into the second sheet.  AGAIN  this is a total crap way to debug

```
Sub Test()
Dim iVal As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        iVal = InStr(1, Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2), "blah")
        MsgBox CStr(iVal)
        If iVal > 0 Then
        'go to second sheet column 1 and enter in the value thats in the 2nd column on sheet 1
        MsgBox "Adding to Sheet 2: " & Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
            Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly, adding the 1 and 0 and value fails to make any difference in the outcome. Thanks for reminding me about proper syntax, but I'm no further along in solving this.

Comment: what is the output you are expecting? Are you expecting blah to be put into the second sheet?

Comment: No, sir. I'm expecting the values of Sheet1 Cells(i, 2) to be put into Sheet2 Cells(i, 1) if "blah" occurs in Sheet1 Cells(i, 1). Nothing happens. No errors. No output. I'm now thinking of trying to read Sheet1 A1-A10 into an array, then search the array for "blah", etc.

Comment: @Max whatever is the problem with your worksheet is not going to be resolved by reading A1-10 into an array...

Comment: Open a brand new worksheet.  Enter blah in every other row on sheet 1 column A.  add a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in the second column on sheet 1.  add the macro above and run it, it does work as that is how I tested and the results in sheet 2 column 1 where a,c,e,g,i.  The issue may be with your data.  take InStr and put the result in a variable and debug what that value is.

Comment: Sorceri, thanks. Still no luck. I wish I could upvote for your assistance, but my rep is still < 15

Comment: run the code I posted now. I think you are checking the wrong column.

Answer (score 1):

If you teach a man to fish... here is not an answer, but how you can figure out the problem on your own:

Add a breakpoint in your code by putting the cursor on the line below, and pressing F9.

`Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)`

If you did it correctly, then you will see it like this in the VBE:

[image]

Press F5 to run your code.

The VBE will highlight this line yellow when/if it hits the line. This essentially pauses code execution so you can examine & trace what's happening.  Here is when you can enter `Debug.Print` statements (or `MsgBox` as per my example and SOrceri's example, above) or you can use the *Immediates* window, or the *Locals* window to examine variables & their values (this is more advanced).

If "nothing" happens (i.e., the line is never highlighted yellow) there are only two things that I can think of.

1. `Sheets(1).Cells(i,2)` is empty, or
2. The condition in your boolean expression is never satisfied.

The breakpoint will allow you to debug and figure out which of those (or potential other conditions that I haven't thought of) might be contributing to the apparent "error".

**Update** I think the problem really is your logic, unfortunately. I will try to provide an example that can be as explicit as possible.

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sht1Cell As Range
Dim sht2Cell As Range
For i = 1 To 10
    Set sht1Cell = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    Set sht2Cell = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1)

    'Now, test whether "blah" is found in sht1Cell:
    If InStr(1, sht1Cell.Value, "blah") > 0 Then
        'If it contains "blah", then put this value in sheet 2.
        'Note: you were previously putting values from Column B.
        '      but this is taking the exact cell value from 
        '      column A, so I KNOW this value cannot be a blank value.
        sht2Cell.Value = sht1Cell.Value
    Else:
        'Does not contain "blah", so make sheet 2 have a blank
        'This blanks out any value that might have previously been
        'present in sh2Cell.
        sht2Cell.Value = ""
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

If this is not achieving the desired results, I am 100% certain the problem is in your logic,  which does not adequately describe the condition(s) and result(s) you hope to achieve. Wherein it differs, is anyone's guess, unless you can more thoroughly describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: David, thanks. Still no luck. I wish I could upvote for your assistance, but my rep is still < 15.

Comment: WHat do you mean "No luck". What happened when you did this?

Comment: Yes, that means the VBE is awaiting you to do something. That's *what a breakpoint does*. Beneath that line, enter this: `MsgBox Sheets(1).Cells(i,2)` to display the value (alternatively you could do `Debug.Print Sheets(1).Cells(i,2) ` or enter `?Sheets(1).Cells(i,2) ` in the Immediates window.

Comment: Okay, we might be getting somewhere. Keep in mind the full string in Sheets(1).Cells(i,2) is "foo to blah" and I'm trying to use InStr to check if that string contains "blah". So, when I run the breakpoint, the msg box says "foo to blah", which is what I would expect.

Comment: Sheets(1).Cells(i,2) is foo to blah but you are checking Sheets(1).Cells(i,1) which is columnm 1

Comment: OK. Are you certain you're actually checking `Sheets(2)` when you try to verify that something happened? If there are many sheets in a workbook, and they have been rearranged, your `Sheet2` tab might not actually be `Sheets(2)`.

Comment: @Sorceri but he did arrive at the breakpoint, so checking the first column "works".  But that is a possibility. I just assumed he was using this to return an offset value from the next column.

Comment: I have now run the break with msg box for both col 1 and 2 and it returns the data contained in each, i.e., "foo to blah" in col 1 and the value or blank in col 2. Blank, because not every row in col 1 contains "foo to blah" -- the purpose of the code being to sort that out.

Comment: Your code is sortinh that out but it is taking the blank value fromcool 2 and writing that to sheet 2

Comment: It's okay to 'write' the blank to Sheet2 as long as that blank is in the row corresponding to no instance of "blah". It seems to be overwriting the "blah"s in the rows where it should not. I fear my syntax is fine, but my logic is not.

Comment: if "blah" is present in the cell, then what *should* be written out to Sheet2?

Comment: The value in Sheet1 col 2

Comment: And what when that value in col 2 is blank?

Comment: Or, show a screenshot of your data. If you can't post it here, upload it to imgur and post the link in the comments here.

Comment: Else Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = "". I updated the code with this, but the outcome has not changed.

Comment: A screenshot of your data would be most helpful.

Comment: The code works if the InStr expression is replaced with the string to be evaluated. The breakpoint shows the correct data. VBA does not seem to like putting a looped range inside of the InStr expression, so, screw it, I'll do it the long way. Thanks to all for your suggestions.

Comment: Max this doesn't make any sense I use loops ALL THE TIME for string functions -- and its woeking for me on this question when i test it out. But if you can't figure it out and can't explain what you're doing (or trying to do) a little more clearly you will have to do it the long way,  however that is.